# Entries of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

The wikipedia article on matrices states:

"..is a rectangular array—of numbers, symbols, or expressions,.."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)

Do you agree with that? Are the entries of a matrix restricted to numbers, symbols and expressions?

Comment: Um, what are you imagining ***isn't*** covered by the word "expressions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that matrix is a rectangular array of either of those as long as matrix addition and matrix multiplication is well defined. If the rectangular array contains something which makes those operations somehow undefined it would be unsuitable or impractical to call it a matrix.